# R - Unlist Data_frame column of lists in tidy manner

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, tidyverse

I have data in a data frame where one column is a list. This is an example:

```
rand_lets <- function(){
  sample(letters[1:26], runif(sample(1:10, 1), min=5, max=12))
}

example_data <- data.frame(ID = seq(1:5),
                           location = LETTERS[1:5],
                           observations = I(list(rand_lets(),
                                                 rand_lets(),
                                                 rand_lets(),
                                                 rand_lets(),
                                                 rand_lets())))
```

I am looking for an elegant tidyverse approach to unlist the list column so that each element in the list is separated into a new column. For example the first row would look like this:

```
ID location observations  observations.1  observations.3  observations.3  observations.4  observations.5  observations.6  observations.7  observations.8  observations.9  
1        A  "y"           "b"             "m"             "u"             "x"             "j"             "t"             "i"             "v"             "w"
```

Of course the lists entries may be different lengths so empty cells should be NA.

How could this be done?

Comment: Long form is almost certainly more useful for ragged data, but if you really want to go directly to wide, you can structure the data within the list column: `example_data %>% mutate(observations = map(observations, ~as_data_frame(t(.x)))) %>% unnest()`

Comment: Awesome. That's a neat use of `map()`. I agree that the long form is more useful but I want to use my dataset in a tutorial and going from the wide form to the long form is a good first lesson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep your data in "long" format, you can do:

```
example_data %>% unnest(observations)
```

> ```
>    ID location observations
> 1   1        A            e
> 2   1        A            x
> 3   1        A            w
> ...
> 44  5        E            u
> 45  5        E            o
> 46  5        E            z
> ```

To spread the data to "wide" format, as in your example, you can do:

```
library(stringr)

example_data %>% unnest(observations) %>%
  group_by(location) %>%
  mutate(counter=paste0("Obs_", str_pad(1:n(),2,"left","0"))) %>%
  spread(counter, observations)
```

> ```
>      ID location Obs_01 Obs_02 Obs_03 Obs_04 Obs_05 Obs_06 Obs_07 Obs_08 Obs_09 Obs_10 Obs_11
> * <int>   <fctr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
> 1     1        A      e      x      w      c      s      j      k      t      z   <NA>   <NA>
> 2     2        B      k      u      d      h      z      x   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
> 3     3        C      v      z      m      o      s      f      n      c      r      u      b
> 4     4        D      z      i      m      s      a      v      n      r      e      t      x
> 5     5        E      f      b      g      h      a      d      u      o      z   <NA>   <NA>
> ```

Comment: Awesome @eipi10 - can you explain why it does not need `group_by(ID, location)` - it appears to me that the group by ID is somehow implied. BTW, `counter=`sprintf("Obs_%02i", 1:n())` may be a neater way to format the headings.

Comment: If you have more than one ID per location or vice versa then use `group_by(ID, location)`.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative for the wide option you can do:

```
example_data %>% unnest_wider(observations, names_sep = "")
```

If your list is named then the names_sep argument is not needed.

```
# A tibble: 5 × 13
     ID location observations1 observations2 observations3 observations4 observations5 observations6 observations7 observations8 observations9 observations10 observations11
  <int> <chr>    <chr>         <chr>         <chr>         <chr>         <chr>         <chr>         <chr>         <chr>         <chr>         <chr>          <chr>         
1     1 A        r             h             q             l             w             c             e             g             NA            NA             NA            
2     2 B        c             q             x             k             d             u             v             w             l             NA             NA            
3     3 C        j             r             w             p             h             k             i             y             m             a              z             
4     4 D        c             x             a             s             t             o             p             q             NA            NA             NA            
5     5 E        h             w             o             p             t             y             k             e             u             NA             NA
```